# VLCKit with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, vlckit

I would like to use **VLCKit** with **SwiftUI**.

why not AVPlayer ? because a some video formats are not supported.

Here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView
            {
                VStack{
                    PlayerView(url: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")
                }
        }
    }
}
struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    public var url: String
    let mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {

        let controller = UIView()
        mediaPlayer.drawable = controller
        let uri = URL(string: self.url)
        let media = VLCMedia(url: uri!)
        mediaPlayer.media = media
        mediaPlayer.play()
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }
}
```

This works and load the video but I would like to add playback controls (Full Screen, Play/Pause, forward, etc.).

I didn't find any documentation about this can anyone help me a bit,

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you find a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I watched this video on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_u9nsXNvn4

and this 
[How to show my AVPlayer in a VStack with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822943/how-to-show-my-avplayer-in-a-vstack-with-swiftui)

Here is my demo

```
import SwiftUI

struct VlcPlayerDemo: UIViewRepresentable{
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VlcPlayerDemo>) {
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView, VLCMediaPlayerDelegate {
  private let mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let url = URL(string: "rtsp://xxxxx")!//replace your resource here

    mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: url)
    mediaPlayer.delegate = self
    mediaPlayer.drawable = self
    mediaPlayer.play()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }
}

struct VlcPlayerDemo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VlcPlayerDemo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileVLCKit

struct VLCPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var mediaUrl: URL?

    @State var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

    typealias UIViewType = UIView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let uiView = UIView()
        mediaPlayer.drawable = uiView
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if let url = mediaUrl {
            mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: url)
            mediaPlayer.play()
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.stop()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var mediaURL: URL? //update this
    var body: some View {
      VLCPlayerView(mediaURL: $mediaURL)
   }
}
```

Comment: will this workable for rtpm video file?

Comment: @ShariifIslam i have not checked with rtmp video file, you may try to use it and update here.

Comment: There is no controll buttons.

Comment: @alex i have added another answer below it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileVLCKit

///A wrapper to use MobileVLCKit media player to play and stop videos

class VLCPlayerWrapper: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var mediaPlayer: VLCMediaPlayer?
    
    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false
    @Published var isBuffering: Bool = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer(options: ["--network-caching=5000"]) // change your media player related options
        mediaPlayer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    ///Method to begin playing the specified URL
    func play(url: URL) {
        let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
        mediaPlayer?.media = media
        mediaPlayer?.play()
    }
    
    ///Method to stop playing the currently playing video
    func stop() {
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
        isPlaying = false
    }

    func pause() {
        if isPlaying {
           mediaPlayer?.pause()
           isPlaying = false
        } else {
           mediaPlayer?.play()
           isPlaying = true
        }
    }

}

extension VLCPlayerWrapper: VLCMediaPlayerDelegate {
    ///Implementation for VLCMediaPlayerDelegate to handle media player state change
    func mediaPlayerStateChanged(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        if let player = mediaPlayer {
            if player.state == .stopped {
                isPlaying = false
                isBuffering = false
            } else if player.state == .playing {
                isPlaying = true
                isBuffering = false
            } else if player.state == .opening {
                isBuffering = true
            } else if player.state == .error {
                stop()
            } else if player.state == .buffering {
            } else if player.state == .paused {
                isPlaying = false
            }
        }
    }
}

///A wrapper which allows the MobileVLCKit to be used with SwiftUI
struct VLCMediaPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UIView
    
    @ObservedObject var playerWrapper: VLCPlayerWrapper
    
    ///Method to create the UIKit view that is to be represented in SwiftUI
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let playerView = UIView()
        return playerView
    }
    
    ///Method to update the UIKit view that is being used in SwiftUI
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if let player = playerWrapper.mediaPlayer {
            player.drawable = uiView
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var playerWrapper: VLCPlayerWrapper = VLCPlayerWrapper()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VLCMediaPlayerView(playerWrapper: playerWrapper)
            .overlay(alignment: .center, content: {
                if self.playerWrapper.isBuffering {
                    VStack {
                        ProgressView() {
                            Text("Bufferning...")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                             .font(.headline)
                        }
                            .tint(.white)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .background(.black)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                }
            })
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    playerWrapper.play(url: /*use @State urlstring property*/)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Play")
                })

                Button(action: {
                   playerWrapper.stop()
                }, label: {
                   Text("Stop")
                })

                Button(action: {
                   playerWrapper.pause()
                }, label: {
                   Text("Pause")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```